# Как найти утечку памяти?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

void random1(int* nPtr, int n) {

    for (int i(0); i < n; i++) {

        *(nPtr + i) = rand() % 10 + 1;

        cout << *(nPtr + i) << " ";

    }

    cout << endl << endl << endl;

}

void random2(int* mPtr, int m) {

    for (int i(0); i < m; i++) {

        *(mPtr + i) = rand() % 10 + 1;

        cout << *(mPtr + i) << " ";

    }

    cout << endl << endl << endl;

}

void Desiigner(int* mPtr, int* nPtr, int* xPtr, int x, int m, int n) {

    int sck;

    int t = 0;

    int k = 0;

    int* aPtr = new int[m + n];

    for (int i(0); i < m; i++) {

        *(aPtr + i) = *(mPtr + i);

        k = i;

    }

    k++;

    int q = 0;

    for (int i(0); i < n; i++, k++) {

        *(aPtr + k) = *(nPtr + i);

    }

    int kof = 0;

    for (int i(0); i < m + n; i++) {

        for (int j(0); j < m + n; j++) {

            if (i == j) {
                j++;
            }

            if (*(aPtr + i) == *(aPtr + j)) {

                kof++;

            }

        }

        if (kof == 0) {

            *(xPtr + q) = *(aPtr + i);

            for (; t < 1; t++) {

                sck = *(xPtr + q);

            }

            if (q > x) {

                break;

            }

            q++;

        }



        kof = 0;


    }

    for (int i(0); i < m + n; i++) {

        cout << *(aPtr + i) << " ";

    }

    cout << endl << endl;

    for (int i(0); i < x; i++) {

        if (*(xPtr + i) < 0) {

            break;

        }

        cout << *(xPtr + i) << " ";

    }



    cout << endl << endl;

    for (int i(0); i < m + n; i++) {

        if (*xPtr == sck) {

            break;

        }

        xPtr--;

    }


    for (int i(0); i < x; i++) {

        cout << *(xPtr + i) << " ";

    }

    cout << endl << *xPtr << endl << endl;



    delete[] aPtr;

}

int main() {

    //srand(time(0));

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "UKR");

    int m, n, x;


    cout << "Введiть кiлькiсть елементiв першого масиву: ";

    cin >> m;

    cout << endl;

    cout << "Введiть кiлькiсть елементiв другого масиву: ";

    cin >> n;

    cout << endl << endl;

    x = (m > n) ? n : m;

    int* mPtr = new int[m];


    int* nPtr = new int[n];

    int* xPtr = new int[x];

    random1(nPtr, n);

    random2(mPtr, m);

    Desiigner(mPtr, nPtr, xPtr, x, m, n);

    delete[] xPtr, nPtr, mPtr;

    system("pause");

    return 0;

}
```

Проблема в xPtr, никак не могу найти ошибку, он на нулевом элементе даже.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99464/discussion-on-question-by-lancet----).

Answer (score 3):

Отвечаю на исходную задачу.

> Даны два массива: А[M] и B[N] (M и N вводятся с клавиатуры).
>   Необходимо создать третий массив минимально возможного размера, в
>   котором нужно собрать общие элементы двух массивов без повторений.

Тег С++. Ну так и пишем.

Для начала чтение массива чисел.

```
std::vector<int> readArray(std::istream &is) { 
   int s;
   std::cin >> s;
   std::vector<int> res;
   std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin),
      s,
      std::back_inserter(res));
   return res;
}
```

Теперь надо бы слить их.

```
std::set<int> r;
auto x = readArray(std::cin);
r.insert(x.begin(), x.end());
x = readArray(std::cin);
r.insert(x.begin(), x.end());
```

А, нам надо массив создать. Ну окей.

```
std::vector<int> final_res(r.begin(), r.end());
std::copy(final_res.begin(), final_res.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
```

В качестве бонуса даже распечатаю новый массив.